# How do I remove the white border in my SwiftUI app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning Swift and my first assignment is to make UI that looks like an employee ID card.

```
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("employeeID")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.red/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .border(Color.red, width: 0)
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

employeeID is just a picture I grabbed from Google Images for testing.

my goal is to make the UI look like

https://www.behance.net/gallery/28292701/Cool-Office-Badge-for-team-mates

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ZStack` with the `background` and the `image` inside.

```
        ZStack (alignment: .top){
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Image("employeeID")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.red/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .border(Color.red, width: 0)
                .fixedSize()
        }
```

If you want to add the name/title to the view, wrap the `Image` in a `VStack` and add the text.

**Result:**

[image]